# JQuery: Create image and div and then append image to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create an image object, then a div object, append the image to the div and finally append the result to a wrapper.

I did this:

```
var image = $(document.createElement('img'));
image.attr('src', url);
image.attr('id', 'preview_gallery_image_' + i);
image.addClass('admin-hotel-gallery-image');
var imageDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
imageDiv.addClass('col-sm-3');
imageDiv.attr('id', 'preview_gallery_image_wrapper_' + i);
var imageNode = image.appendTo(imageDiv);
var finalElement = imageNode.appendTo("#gallery-wrapper");
```

To make it a bit clearer, the final result should look like this:

```
<div id="gallery-wrapper>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="preview-gallery-image-wrapper-1">
        <img url="...">
    </div>
</div>
```

What I get is only the image in the gallery wrapper, but the inner imageDiv around the image is missing:

```
<div id="gallery-wrapper>
    <img url="...">
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't appended div to dom elements.

Comment: You're not using jQuery. Use `$('<img />').attr({src: url, id: 'preview_gallery_image_' + i}).addClass('admin-hotel-gallery-image');`

Comment: @Mohammad: the div with the id gallery-wrapper is an existing div and what I tried was creating an image, creating a div, then append the image to the div and then append the result to an existing div. So, didn't I append image and wrapping div to an existing dom?

Comment: @rockie667 You problem is that you didn't append `div` to `gallery-wrapper`. You need to use `imageDiv.appendTo("#gallery-wrapper")` instead of `imageNode.appendTo("#gallery-wrapper")`. See https://jsfiddle.net/rhkfk8p6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/n3qge993/7/)

**js code**

```
var url = 'url';
var i =1 ;

var image = $('<img />', { 
 id:'preview_gallery_image_' + i,
 class: 'admin-hotel-gallery-image' ,
 src: url
});

var imageDiv = $('<div >',{
  id: 'preview_gallery_image_wrapper_' + i
});

image.appendTo(imageDiv);



var finalElement = $('<div/>',{
  id: 'gallery-wrapper' 
});

imageDiv.appendTo(finalElement);
finalElement.appendTo('body');
```

**result:**

```
<div id="gallery-wrapper">
    <div id="preview_gallery_image_wrapper_1">
        <img src="url" class="admin-hotel-gallery-image" id="preview_gallery_image_1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You rescued me after hours and hours of struggling with this issue... :) But I am still not sure, what I did wrong! But anyway - it works now... :) Thanks again!

Comment: you use $(document.createElement('div')); insted of $('<div/>')